# sublime text: how to make the cursor go to the beginning of a find text

Tags: sublimetext3

In sublime text when i find some text using regex assuming `START.*END` where i want to find text between START and END words.

Now after findind we see the cursor is located after the END word. Is it possible to put the cursor before START word

Or is there a keyboard shortcut which can bring the cursor to ahead of START.

Because if i do `CTRL + LEFT` it will take me to the next `. (dot)` or  `space` etc

If i do `HOME` then it will go to the beginning of the line

Comment: If cursor is located at END, then you can press Home button to move the cursor before start.

Comment: that will go to the beginning to the line

Comment: The `find` always puts the cursor after the found text and as far as I know there's no way to change that (short of maybe using a third party search plugin or something). However whenever text is selected, if you press `Left` or `Right` the cursor will jump to that end of the selection. So in this case if you do the search, as long as the text is still selected just pressing `Left` once should get you where you want to be.

Answer (score 3):

As user @[OdatNurd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/814803/odatnurd) mention in comments, after you search and select all occurrences, press <kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> arrow to go to beginning or end of selection.

*Example*: 
after selecting all occurrences, press <kbd>Left</kbd> to go to the beginning of a selection and edit.

[image: Edit example]

Comment: But if you are having multiple words and searched using regex like "ABC*PXY" * can have any number of words